# Converting a triple of lists into a list of triples in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, tuples

I know zip does this with pairs but I do not think there is a function that does this with triples? How would I make one? Or failing that, how would I add each member of the third list onto each pair in turn, thus making a list of triples?

Answer (score 8):

Try to use [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=zip3) :

Some functions from Prelude:

```
zip3 :: [a] -> [b] -> [c] -> [(a, b, c)]
```

By the way revert functions exist:

```
unzip :: [(a, b)] -> ([a], [b])

unzip3 :: [(a, b, c)] -> ([a], [b], [c])
```

If currying is needed, we could add

```
uncurry3 f (x, y, z) = f x y z

uncurry3 zip3 :: ([a], [b], [c]) -> [(a, b, c)]
```

Comment: You might also be able to use [`zipWith3 :: (a -> b -> c -> d) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c] -> [d]`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v:zipWith3) in lieu of `uncurry3`, depending on what you were doing.

Answer (score 1):

```
zip3 (x:xs) (y:ys) (z:zs) = (x,y,z) : zip3 xs ys zs
zip3 _      _      _      = []
```